# Identification help - hybrid chips

Tags: identification

I need help identifying these two IC's. They were in my father's electronics shop and I found them in a box. There are many of them. I searched the net and could not find any info at all so was hoping someone here would know.

[image: Two mystery IC's]

[image]

Comment: Going to be more or less impossible. These aren't really ICs so much as hybrids, small ceramic PCBs with who knows what inside. Probably from week 10 of 1978 and week 2 of 1980. MX2006 doesn't help much. The 8-digit code (8019 3315) looks like a large company's internal part number. If you know which you can look it up in their internal catalog (if you can find one). Hewlett-Packard and Burroughs did this; maybe others too. That's as far as I can get.

Comment: If you've got lots why not open one up and post a photo of whatever you find inside.  On part number, another possibility is that it's "2006-1" and "2006-1 R" for revised, with "78 8019 3315 7" being an internal inventory number as @BrianDrummond suggested.

Comment: It might help to know what country your father lived in during the time he acquired these, and if he worked for a big electronics company, which one.

Comment: I also feel similarly with @BrianDrummond's comments. Hybrids were often made in ceramics like this in the late 1970's and early 1980's. I used some specialized devices like this which were custom filter designs around that time (they were bigger than those, though.) The HH symbol on the later-manufactured device invokes Hitachi Hokkai Semiconductor to mind. But it's just a random wag from me.

Comment: What’s that double H-logo from on the bottom device before 2006?

Comment: @winny That's what my comment addresses. It's just a wild guess, but it might be "Hitachi Hokkai". But since I never used their parts and don't actually know the years they existed, it's entirely a random guess from me.

Comment: @jonk Sorry about that.

Comment: These were located in Toronto where my father worked in the electronics field as a technologist from the late 1940's until the mid 2000's.

Comment: So you got the lid off. 8 unknown (possibly transistors) with goop protecting the bond wires, on a hybrid as expected. Resistors are printed on (like the grey bits protruding from the blue conformal coating ... possibly for test access? What it is or does is anybody's guess. Could be an 8-bit DAC 9they weren't all ICs back then) or an 8-way analog switch or ...)

Answer (score 1):

So looks like this is likely a hybrid with eight transistors. Function unknown. Possibly an 8-bit DAC or 8 way analog switch. The double H logo could mean Hitachi Hokkai Semicondictor.